# MySql how to avoid having to create temporary tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm very new to SQL and have a query that I need to use through a WordPress plugin ([WP Data Tables](http://wpdatatables.com/)) but the plugin doesn't allow the creation of temporary tables.

To work around this I believe I have to create new tables within a join but I'm not sure how to do this.

The query I need to remove the creation of table from is:

```
create temporary table if not exists _SurveyData AS

(SELECT 
    _RefTable.RefID,
    _RefTable.ClientRef,
    _RefTable.SiteName,
    _JobTable.JobID,
    _JobTable.JobTypeID,
    _JobTable.JobClosedDate 
FROM
    _RefTable, _JobTable
WHERE
    _RefTable.RefID = _JobTable.RefID and  _JobTable.JobTypeID = 1);

create temporary table if not exists _InstallData AS

(SELECT 
    _RefTable.RefID,
    _RefTable.ClientRef,
    _RefTable.SiteName,
    _JobTable.JobID,
    _JobTable.JobTypeID,
    _JobTable.JobClosedDate 
FROM
    _RefTable, _JobTable
WHERE
    _RefTable.RefID = _JobTable.RefID and  _JobTable.JobTypeID = 2);

SELECT
    _RefTable.RefID,
    _RefTable.ClientRef,
    _RefTable.SiteName,
    _SurveyData.JobID,
    _SurveyData.JobClosedDate,
    _InstallData.JobID,
    _InstallData.JobClosedDate
from
    _RefTable, _SurveyData, _InstallData
Where
    _RefTable.RefID = _SurveyData.RefID and _RefTable.RefID = _InstallData.RefID
    order by RefID
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Temporary table into sub queries.

Try this:

```
SELECT _RefTable.RefID,
    _RefTable.ClientRef,
    _RefTable.SiteName,
    _SurveyData.JobID,
    _SurveyData.JobClosedDate,
    _InstallData.JobID,
    _InstallData.JobClosedDate
from RefTable
INNER JOIN(
            SELECT 
            _RefTable.RefID,
            _RefTable.ClientRef,
            _RefTable.SiteName,
            _JobTable.JobID,
            _JobTable.JobTypeID,
            _JobTable.JobClosedDate 
                FROM RefTable, _JobTable WHERE _RefTable.RefID = _JobTable.RefID and  _JobTable.JobTypeID = 1
            ) as _SurveyData on _RefTable.RefID = _SurveyData.RefID 
INNER JOIN(
            SELECT 
            _RefTable.RefID,
            _RefTable.ClientRef,
            _RefTable.SiteName,
            _JobTable.JobID,
            _JobTable.JobTypeID,
            _JobTable.JobClosedDate 
            FROM  _RefTable, _JobTable WHERE _RefTable.RefID = _JobTable.RefID and  _JobTable.JobTypeID = 2
        ) as _InstallData on _RefTable.RefID = _InstallData.RefID
order by RefID;
```

Comment: I get the error #1146 - Table 'CerteqWebDB.RefTable' doesn't exist

Comment: Hold on one of the tables were missing the _ prefix, all working now :D